# Battery Storage Pyomo: optimize and iterate yearly data over a 365 hours time horizon

Tags: python, iteration, pyomo, battery, chunks

I have yearly data on electricity prices called 'HOEP'. With my pyomo model, I want to determine the behavior of a battery for the whole year but with a 365 hours time horizon (energy in = Ein and energy out = Eout). In other words, I want to make my  algorithm run for the first 365 hours, then run again the next 365 hours time horizon with initial battery state equal to the last hour of the previous time horizon period.

I have tried dividing my yearly data into chunks (24 chunks of 365 hours in the year). With df_list = np.vsplit(dfa, 24), I create a list of chunks and transform them into 24 different dataframe. Then, I use for idx, df in enumerate([df0, df1, df2]), (here is only 3 chunks for testing) before my model to loop over the data. However, when I look at my results, it seems that the model only optimize for the last argument of enumerate([df0, df1, df2]) which is df2.

Does anybody know why it does not work for the 3 chunks? Or how could I do this in a different way?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Here is the edited version of my code that works now but I know it is porbably not the most pythonic way of doing this.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from typing import List
from itertools import chain
from pyomo.environ import *

output = []

for idx, df in enumerate([df0,df1,df2]):

    model = ConcreteModel()
    
    # Variables of the model
    model.T = Set(initialize=df.hour.tolist(), ordered=True)
    model.Rmax = Param(initialize=1, within=Any) 
    model.Smax = Param(initialize=5, within=Any)
    model.Dmax = Param(initialize=5, within=Any) 

    model.Ein = Var(model.T, domain=NonNegativeReals)  
    model.Eout = Var(model.T, domain=NonNegativeReals) 
    model.Z = Var(model.T, domain=NonNegativeReals)  
    model.L = Var(model.T, domain=NonNegativeReals) 
    model.NES = Var(model.T)

    # Constraints
    def storage_state(model, t):
        if t == model.T.first():
            return model.Z[t] == 0
        else:
            return (model.Z[t] == (model.Z[t-1] + (model.Ein[t]) - (model.Eout[t])))                         
    model.charge_state = Constraint(model.T, rule=storage_state)

    def discharge_constraint(model, t):
        return model.Eout[t] <= model.Rmax
    model.discharge = Constraint(model.T, rule=discharge_constraint)
    
    def charge_constraint(model, t):
        return model.Ein[t] <= model.Rmax
    model.charge = Constraint(model.T, rule=charge_constraint)

    def positive_charge(model, t): 
        return model.Eout[t] <= model.Z[t] 
    model.positive_charge = Constraint(model.T, rule=positive_charge)

    def max_SOC(model, t): 
        return model.Z[t] <= model.Smax
    model.max_SOC = Constraint(model.T, rule=max_SOC)

    def demand_constraint(model, t):
        return (model.L[t] == (df.loc[t, 'MktDemand'] + (model.Ein[t]) - (model.Eout[t]))) 
    model.demand_constraint = Constraint(model.T, rule=demand_constraint)

    def discharge_limit(model, t):    
        max_t = model.T.last()
        if t < max_t - 24:
            return sum(model.Eout[i] for i in range(t, t+24)) <= model.Dmax
        else:
            return Constraint.Skip
    model.limit_disch_out = Constraint(model.T, rule=discharge_limit)

    def charge_limit(model, t):    
        max_t = model.T.last()
        if t < max_t - 24:
            return sum(model.Ein[i] for i in range(t, t+24)) <= model.Dmax
        else:
            return Constraint.Skip
    model.limit_charg_out = Constraint(model.T, rule=charge_limit)

    def Net_energy_sold(model, t):
        return model.NES[t] == ((model.Eout[t] - model.Ein[t]) / model.Rmax * 100)                       
    model.net_energy = Constraint(model.T, rule=Net_energy_sold)

    # Objective function and optimization
    income = sum(df.loc[t,'HOEP'] * model.Eout[t] for t in model.T)
    expenses = sum(df.loc[t,'HOEP'] * model.Ein[t] for t in model.T)
    profits = (income - expenses) 
    model.objective = Objective(expr=profits, sense=maximize)

    # Solve model
    solver = SolverFactory('glpk')
    solver.solve(model) 
    
    # Extract model output in list
    Date = list(df['Date'])
    output.append([Date, model.Ein.get_values().values(), model.Eout.get_values().values(), 
                    model.Z.get_values().values(), model.NES.get_values().values(), 
                    model.L.get_values().values()])
    
df_results = pd.DataFrame(output)
df_results.rename(columns = {0: 'Date', 1: 'Ein', 2:'Eout', 3:'Z', 4:'NES', 5:'Load'}, inplace = True)
df_results

# Present final results in dataframe
d = ein = eout = z = l = nes = []

for i in list(df_results.index):
    d = d + list(df_results.loc[i,'Date'])
    ein = ein + list(df_results.loc[i,'Ein'])
    eout = eout + list(df_results.loc[i,'Eout'])
    z = z + list(df_results.loc[i,'Z'])
    nes = nes + list(df_results.loc[i,'NES'])
    l = l + list(df_results.loc[i,'Load'])

results = pd.DataFrame(zip(d, ein, eout, z, nes, l), columns = ['Date','Ein','Eout','SOC','NES','Load'])
results 


# Returned dataframe

            Date  Ein  Eout   SOC    NES      Load
0     2019-01-01  0.0  0.00  0.00    0.0  16231.00
1     2019-01-01  0.0  0.00  0.00    0.0  16051.00
2     2019-01-01  1.0  0.00  1.00 -100.0  15806.00
3     2019-01-01  1.0  0.00  2.00 -100.0  15581.00

...
```

Comment: where is `dfb` defined? It's used when creating `list_of_series` but it doesn't seem to be initialized anywhere. Is it a typo?

Comment: is there a specific reason why you want to optimize based on 365 hours? e.g., would optimizing based on weeks, or months, work for you? just asking because it's very easy to group-by based on weeks or months, and leap years don't have a multiple of 365 hours.

Comment: I chose 365 hours just because it would be easy to have chunks of the same size. But chunk of 14 days could work too!

Comment: I've edited the code so now dfb is defined above.

Answer (score 1):

## Why it isn't working

(disclaimer: this is one issue I see, there might be others).

At each iteration of the for loop, `list_of_series` is defined from scratch, so all the results obtained in previous iterations are lost.

I'd also check that `df.hour` is "hour of the year" or "hour from beginning of data" rather than "hour of the day" (if it's the latter, this will also cause an error).

## Fixing the problem

(there are several solutions, obviously) at each iteration of the for loop, turn `list_of_series` into a `pd.DataFrame`, and append the dataframe to a list.
At the end of the for loop (once you have run the model on each chunk of data), *concatenate* the list of dataframes.

```py
from typing import List

...

# find a better name, variable names shouldn't specify the type
list_of_dataframes: List[pd.DataFrame] = []
for ...:  # for each chunk of data
    ...  # create model, solve
    list_of_series = ...
    list_of_dataframes.append(pd.DataFrame(list_of_series))

results = pd.concat(list_of_dataframes, axis=0) # use `ignore_index=True` if needed
```

## A few tips

1. Break your code into functions. Create a function which defines the model. That highlights what inputs and outputs are, makes the for loop more readable, allows you to use it in other contexts and potentially to test it.
2. (opinionated) set your "data" as parameters of the model, instead of using them directly to construct constraints and the objective function. This allows you to have a single place where each piece of data is ingested in the model, creates internal consistency in the model and allows you to extract results purely based on the optimized model.
3. separate I/O (reading/writing to file) from the rest of the code. If your data source changes format or filetype, you'll be able to change that without changing any of the rest of the code.

```py
def main(input_data: pd.DataFrame) -> pd.DataFrame:
    # group by week, month, or any applicable resolution
    # this assumes the index is a `pd.DatetimeIndex`
    # `MS` is "Month Start" - watch out with weeks because `freq="w"` starts
    # on Mondays, and your data might start on a different weekday.
    # If you want split into chunks of some number of days,
    # use e.g. `freq="14d"`
    grouped = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="MS"))
    
    results_list: List[pd.DataFrame] = []
    for month, group in grouped:
        model = create_model(group)
        optimization_results = SolverFactory('glpk').solve(model)
        results_list.append(extract_results(model)) # pass `group` if needed
    results = pd.concat(results_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)
    return results


def create_model(df: pd.DataFrame) -> ConcreteModel:
    # NOTE: instead of hard-coding parameters such as battery capacity,
    # pass them as inputs to the function.
    model = ConcreteModel()
    ...

    return model


def extract_results(model: ConcreteModel) -> pd.DataFrame:
    ...


def load_data(filename) -> pd.DataFrame:
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
     input_data = load_data(...)
     results = main(input_data)
     results.to_csv(...)
```

Comment: Hi Giorgio, Thanks for your comment. So in your part of code "Fixing the Problem", the for ...: (for loop) should come at the end of my initial for loop across dataframes and should it be again the for loop over the dataframe like this for example?   ``` for idx, df in enumerate([df0, df1, df2]):

Comment: That _is_ your for loop `for idx, df in enumerate([df0, df1, df2]): ...`.
So at the bottom of (each iteration of) your existing for loop, create a dataframe and append that to a list of dataframes. Once the whole for loop is done, concatenate the list of dataframes into a single dataframe.

Comment: Not exactly. Maybe it is because I wasn't enough clear in the code but result is defined as the output of the objective model ``` lresults = SolverFactory('glpk').solve(model) ``` so it is a pyomo object and cannot be treated as a list that I append. I managed to create a list with the results of the optimization but when concatenating them, I would get a dataframe ouput with 3 rows (one for each item of the for loop) and multiple values in each cell of that dataframe.

Comment: I updated the code in the question with what is working so far

Comment: I hadn't realized `results` was already used. There was a typo that I fixed: you should be appending to `list_of_dataframes` (again, it's a bad variable name).
I'm then calling `results` the "final" `results`. Besides the implementation details, is the idea clear?

Comment: Yess it is ! Thank you Giorgio.

Comment: @Giordio, I'm also trying to create chunks in the dataframe like you suggested using  grouped = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="15d")). I'm able to create the chunks and loop over it. However when I assign each group.index as the Set to my model, I get an error when I try to refer to [t-1] index value. Here is part of the code:                                       `for idx, group in grouped:

    model = ConcreteModel()
    
    # Variables of the model
    model.T = Set(initialize=group.index, ordered=True) ` , so

Comment: The problem happens at this line where I use [t-1]:  ```  # Constraints
        def storage_state(model, t):
            if t == model.T.first():
                return model.Z[t] == 0
            else:
                return (model.Z[t] == (model.Z[t-1] + (model.Ein[t]) - (model.Eout[t])))  ```.                                    I undertand that the issue is that I cannot tell pyomo to refer to  `[2019-01-01 01:00:00  -  1] `. How could I change my constraint to make it understand that I want the to refer to the previous row then? Thanks

Comment: I would _not_ use the actual datetimes in the index, but ordinal values (0, 1, 2, ...), just use `model.T = Set(initialize=range(len(group.index)))`, and access the dataframe values with `.iloc` when constructing the model.

Comment: Stackoverflow is to ask questions, not to get your code debugged. If you have issues, try to frame them as general questions that can be relevant to others, and open a separate question.